# Latest Boot Camp drivers for Windows 7

Tags: drivers, boot-camp

I've just recently received my new MacBook Pro, and I've begun exploring Boot Camp; dual-booting Windows 7 Enterprise.

I've heard chatter that there are some new Boot Camp drivers--newer than the ones that come with your OSX Show Leopard installation CD. But I'm having a hard time locating them.

These updated drivers should fix a few issues with the trackpad, amongst other things.

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to these articles

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3986

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl979

You'll need both your Mac OS X v10.6 installation and Windows 7 installation discs. Here is the general process:

1. Install Windows 7 using the Boot Camp Setup Assistant (located in /Applications/Utilities), which partitions your hard drive and walks you through the installation process. The process differs depending on whether you are performing a new install of Windows 7 or an upgrade install from an earlier version of Windows (see Boot Camp Installation & Setup Guide for more information).
2. After completing the Windows 7 installation, install the Apple Boot Camp Windows drivers from your Mac OS X v10.6 (or later) Install DVD.
3. Upgrade the drivers to Version 3.1 with Windows Apple Software Update, or manually download them from here.

Comment: Great! But do I need to install Boot Camp drivers from my installation disc first off? Or do I just install the update?

Comment: @roosteronacid you would need to install the drivers from the Max OS X first and then perform the upgrade